# Why do neo4j cypher node(*) queries not execute programatically?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are trying Neo4j 1.9, we found that the node(*) queries run fine in the shell, but when we tried the same queries programatically, it just throws "org.neo4j.cypher.ParameterWrongTypeException: Expected a propertycontainer or number here, but got: *"

We even tried using parameter substitution, but no luck!  Is this intentional or a bug? If intentional, can someone explain why?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a parameter for "*" but use it literally:

```
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("start n=node(*) return count(*) as c",params);
```